# How to redefine \the\year

Tags: date

I used `\the\year` many times on a template. So when I compile the document, the current year is used.

The problem is that I created many documents last year, in 2017, and now I have to fix some small parts.

How to redefine `\the\year` to print 2017 instead of 2018?

I don't want to find/replace to write 2017 by hand.

Comment: `\year` is a counter register. Just do `\year=2017` and it will work. Try this: `\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\year=2017
\today
\end{document}`

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik, perfect. I suspected about counter, but I tried only `setcounter`.

Comment: If you mean to get 2017 in the printout, type 2017 or define your own macro. Leave `\year` alone.

Comment: @Sigur `\setcounter` only works if the counter was created with `\newcounter`. When you do `\newcounter{year}`, for example, the counter register created is `\c@year`. That's why `\setcounter` didn't work. Following egreg's advice you could create a `\newcounter{year}`, then `\setcounter{year}{\year}`, or `\setcounter{year}{2017}`, then use `\theyear` instead (of course this would require some find/replace).

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik, your solution worked very well. Since the ideal is to compile and print the document around October of every year, I believe that no other changes will be necessary. So, your solution worked very well in this particular case. Please, post an answer, if you wish.

Comment: @egreg, since the template was adapted by me a long time ago (so my knowledge was much more basic) I just used `\year` because I supposed that it would be more professional. Now it is first time I have to change the year date to fix something. I'll consider to update the template soon. Regards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As requested :)

When you create a LaTeX counter, you give a "symbolic" name. For example, `\newcounter{year}` gives access to a counter register that can be accessed with `\c@year`. So when you use `\setcounter{year}`, the counter used is `\c@year`.

`\year`, as well as `\month`, `\day`, and `\time` are *primitive* counter registers (*i.e.:* not allocated with `\newcount` nor accessible with `\count<n>`), and you cannot use them with LaTeX counters. So to change their value you have to use TeX's syntax:

```
\year=2017
```

For example, if you compile this document:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\year=2017
\today
\end{document}
```

you'll have today's date, but a year back.

But these counters are expected to contain the current date so, as egreg said in his comment, "Leave `\year` alone". For example, the LaTeX kernel contains a check to see if the version is more than 5 year old (disabled). Other packages may rely on something similar, so it would be better not to do it.

Comment: Thanks. Since I'm not going to compile those files anymore (I did just to fix some typos), your solution was OK. For this year I'm going to use the same template or maybe updated, but the year should be 2018, so it will work.